# Is this a javascript array with objects in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Square brackets is an array, and curly brackets are objects correct?

What exactly is this data structure:

```
Some.thing = [ {
  "swatch_src" : "/images/91388044000.jpg",
  "color" : "black multi",
  "inventory" : {
    "F" : [ 797113, 797114 ],
    "X" : [ 797111, 797112 ]
  },
  "images" : [ {
    "postfix" : "jpg?53_1291146215000",
    "prefix" : "/images/share/uploads/0000/0000/5244/52445892"
  }, {
    "postfix" : "jpg?53_1291146217000",
    "prefix" : "/images/share/uploads/0000/0000/5244/52445904"
  }, {
    "postfix" : "jpg?53_1291146218000",
    "prefix" : "/images/share/uploads/0000/0000/5244/52445909"
  } ],
  "skus" : [ {
    "sale_price" : 199,
    "sku_id" : 797111,
    "msrp_price" : 428,
    "size" : "s"
  }, {
    "sale_price" : 199,
    "sku_id" : 797112,
    "msrp_price" : 428,
    "size" : "m"
  }, {
    "sale_price" : 199,
    "sku_id" : 797113,
    "msrp_price" : 428,
    "size" : "l"
  }, {
    "sale_price" : 199,
    "sku_id" : 797114,
    "msrp_price" : 428,
    "size" : "xl"
  } ],
  "look_id" : 37731360
} ];;
```

Comment: It is an array, with an object (associative array) in it. Inside the object, there are other arrays and objects. I don't see why you are starting with `[{` and ending with `}]`, though. Also `;;` isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an array of objects with nested arrays within. (or in this case one single element contained within an array.)

`Some.thing[0]` refers to everything you have listed. From there, you have an object containing:

```
var obj = Some.thing[0];
obj.swatch_src // contains "/images/91388044000.jpg"
obj.color // contains "black multi"
...
obj.inventory // (another object
  obj.inventory.F // array of [797113, 797114]
...
obj.images // array of objects
  obj.images[0].postfix // contains "jpg?53_1291146215000"
  obj.images[0].prefix // contains "/images/share/uploads/0000/0000/5244/52445892"
...
```

Answer (score 4):

`Some.thing` is an array `[]` containing a single object `{}`. Some of the properties of this object are strings while others are arrays.

The single object appears to be describing a product.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is called [JSON: JavaScript Object Notation](http://www.json.org/).

Answer (score 1):

[image: See it yourself]

This is captured from Chrome Console. You can try it yourself :)